# MS Access VBA skip insert to one of the table

Tags: vba, ms-access

I was writing a VBA code for a button on a form. The purpose of it should be, Add data to table Apartment and table Owner. However, it skips the Apartment table and just add to data to Owner table. I also don't receive any bug alerts, everything looks that it went through but Apartment table is still empty. Here is my code.

```
Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()
    'add to apartment
    CurrentDb.Execute " INSERT INTO Apartment(Apartment, Account_ID, Total_area, Heated_area, People) " & _
           " VALUES ( " & Me.txtApt & ",'" & Me.txtAcc & "','" & _
           Me.txtTotal_area & "','" & Me.txtHeated_area & "','" & Me.txtPeople & "')"
    'add to owner
    CurrentDb.Execute " INSERT INTO Owner (Account, FName, LName, MName) " & _
           " VALUES ( " & Me.txtAcc & ",'" & Me.txtFName & "','" & _
           Me.txtLName & "','" & Me.txtMName & "')"
    'clear
    cmdClear_Click

    'subform requery
    frmAptSub.Form.Requery
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may help you to evaluate the SQL statement you are executing so you can see exactly what is going on:-

```
Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()
dim sSQL as string
sSQL = " INSERT INTO Apartment(Apartment, Account_ID, Total_area, Heated_area, People) " & _
       " VALUES ( " & Me.txtApt & ",'" & Me.txtAcc & "','" & _
       Me.txtTotal_area & "','" & Me.txtHeated_area & "','" & Me.txtPeople & "')"
'add to apartment
debug.print sSQL
CurrentDb.Execute sSQL, dbFailOnError
'add to owner
sSQL = " INSERT INTO Owner (Account, FName, LName, MName) " & _
       " VALUES ( " & Me.txtAcc & ",'" & Me.txtFName & "','" & _
       Me.txtLName & "','" & Me.txtMName & "')"
debug.print sSQL
CurrentDb.Execute sSQL, dbFailOnError '... etc
```

Note also the use of dbFailOnError, so if there is something preventing insert into Apartment table (constraint, key violation etc) then an error will be raised so you can check details.

Comment: Thanks, it worked.
Once add dbFailOnError and debug I noticed that I had 1-1 relationship between tables and after I switched to 1-m everything started to work smoothly.